# Using google autocomplete places Javascript API can you bias results to a 'type' of location?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api

I am using the following API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

I would like to restrict results as follows:

If a user has selected 'Airplane' - then the results should show only airports near the place typed by the user.

Likewise, if a user has selected 'Train' - then the results should show only train stations near the place typed by the user.

I don't see any documentation on that particular page suggesting this is possible. I have however elsewhere spotted a 'type' parameter which you can use....not sure how to work that here though.

Alternatively, I have thought - if the user selects 'Airport' I could always just append airport to their search query.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, currently the `types` parameter of places autocomplete supports only following values:

- geocode
- address
- establishment
- (regions)
- (cities)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker to allow types mentioned in the http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html in the places autocomplete.

Please take a look at this feature request:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820774

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote.